# What do you call the person in charge of a district?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the Middle East, each district has a chief recognized by the authorities. He/she is not a government employee but usually the longest residing citizen in the area.
Their duties include verifying people's identities or place of residence. For example, if you want to register your child in school and you are living in a friend or relative's house and don't have a proof of residence, this person would provide you with a letter stating that you do reside in the area and the district school would accept it.

Is there such system in the west? If yes, what is the appellation of such person?

I thought of "*district chief*" but I can't say I am 100% sure...

Comment: What is this person called in Arabic?

Comment: Mukhtar.. the chosen person

Comment: This system seems very medieval to my British mind; the fact that someone gets power simply for being old is (forgetting the House of Lords) simply ridiculous. As such, there is not modern equivalent of this word. However, you may be interested in the olde-worlde term '*elder*' which covers a wise old person who is looked to for guidance but they only really exist or have any power in games and films set in the olden days.

Comment: never heard of such system in the West, the closest would be in some countries like Ireland in the 90's you'd be sometime asked a letter of reference from someone "notable" (a priest, a policeman, a bank manager)  for stuff similar to your example. You'll also find Commissioner of oath in Canada. Someone who uses his reputation (not a government employee) to officially validate a document.

Comment: There simply isn't anything like such a system in the US.

Comment: The closest things I can think of are neighbourhood councils and community leaders.

Comment: In South Africa traditional leaders hold sway over millions of mainly rural residents. These leaders are grouped into kings, chiefs and headmen/women. They hold court and decide issues.Polygamy is common within such communities. The country's president, Jacob Zuma, has several wives. (http://businesstech.co.za/news/government/88860)

Comment: In English, when not being applied to a particular country, "district" is a somewhat vague term.  It only acquires a specific meaning in the context of a particular country's laws.

Comment: As to a person responsible for "public records", in most of the US that would be the "county clerk".  A more general term (though usually associated with colleges) is "registrar".  And "notary" carries a little of this connotation.

Comment: During the days of the British Raj in India, the senior administrator of a 'district' was a British civil servant dubbed the 'District Commissioner'. This may well have been the case with Britain's colonies in Africa.

Answer (score 2):

*Mukhtar* is a word in English too (although I've never heard it before):

> (in Turkey and some Arab countries) the head of local government of a town or village.
>
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mukhtar)</sub>

The responsibilities of a mukhtar are unique; **there's nothing exactly the same in the west** (which is why we borrowed the term).

I'm not an expert in law (especially *Middle Eastern law*), so [this Turkish site](http://www.tbb.gov.tr/en/local-authorities/types-of-local-governments/) helped to explain some of their duties:

> Villages
>
> The mukhtar is both the representative of the village and symbolizes the state in the village. The Village Law ... imposes significant functions and responsibilities on the mukhtar as well as equips him/her with very important powers. The mukhtar plays an active role in ensuring the security of the village and procuring all public services. S/he facilitates the work of central government agencies.
>
> Neighborhoods
>
> The neighbourhood mukhtar serves as a bridging link between the neighbourhood residences and public bodies including particularly the municipality. The mukhtar discharges such significant functions as identifying the poor and provision of assistance, renewing voter registers, informing the relevant agencies of problems and failures in services of education, health, security and sanitation etc.

In my experience, these duties are handled by the government (spread through multiple departments and entities it subcontracts with). On the other hand, in the US at least, nobody needs to help prove your residency ([if you don't have something like a driver's license, your mail will work instead](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/6626/5348)).

Of course, there isn't one "system in the west", and there are various differences between each one. (You can often find different systems inside sovereignties themselves, such as state law in the US.)

Comment: Please provide a reference that Mukhtar is a word in English. In other words, where does your dictionary quote come from? (Otherwise, good answer though).

Answer (score 1):

I would translate *mukhtar* as ***chieftain***:

> 1. the chief of a clan or a tribe.
> 2. a leader of a group, band, etc.: *the robbers' chieftain*.
>
> **Historical Examples**
>
> During a formal visit to the *chieftain* of the tribe, he was offered
>   tea.
>   *[The Soul of a Child](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/12283/12283-h/12283-h.htm)  Edwin Bjorkman*
>
> The *chieftain* gave his orders for the defense of the village.
>   *[Despoilers of the Golden Empire](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/24091/24091-h/24091-h.htm) Gordon Randall Garrett*

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chieftain

Answer (score 0):

While this is not an exact match of duties, a ["notary public"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notary_public) might work.